# How to use navigation in this function from importing a hook within this function? any idea?

Tags: react-native, function, navigation, react-navigation, hook

I am using a function to call an api and i have added navigation on 401 and i want to use navigation here. But as the hooks can be called from the component only. So anybody can tell me how can i add navigation here. So someone i can import here and use while passing in the function.

```
const GetApiRequestWithToken = async (url, params, headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(base_url_address + url, { headers: headers }).then(resp => {
            if (resp.status == 401) {
                UnAuthorizedLogout()
            } else {
                resolve(resp)
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            resolve(error.response)
        });
    })
}
```

So this is a function and how can i import navigation in this. from hooks or some other way.

As this is not allowing to import here

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and i don't want that everytime, i call GetApiRequestWithToken then pass navigation to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation provider pattern to achieve this.  You can create a utility file like the following:

```js
// util/navigation.js
import React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(routeName, params);
};
```

This stores the navigator reference in a local variable.  You can see that it requires the navigator object to be passed in by an external component.  I would recommend calling this function in your top-level navigation stack component.  You most likely already have a component that looks something like the below:

```js
// NavigationContainer.js
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from 'util/navigation';  // from util
import ExampleStack from './ExampleStack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>  {/* store ref */}
            <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Example"
                ...
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Example"
                    component={ExampleStack}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

You can see here that the component created by `createNavigationContainer` will pass the ref to your navigation provider util above.

Finally, you can use the NavigationContainer created in this second file inside your App.js.

```js
// App.js
import NavigationContainer from './NavigationContainer';


export default () => (
  <NavigationContainer />
);
```

Any other functions of the navigator can be added to `navigationUtil.js` now, for example `goBack`.  You can now use the utility in your axios request like so:

```js
// axios util
import { navigate } from './navigationUtil.js'; // new

const GetApiRequestWithToken = async (url, params, headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(base_url_address + url, { headers: headers }).then(resp => {
            if (resp.status == 401) {
                navigate('UnauthorizedLogoutScreen');  // new
                UnAuthorizedLogout();
            } else {
                resolve(resp)
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            resolve(error.response)
        });
    })
}
```

I hope this is clear, feel free to ask if something has not been covered.

Comment: this is looking good but as we need to do a lot of work to achieve it. That i want to avoid that's i am looking for a short and efficient way to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only way to access the navigator outside of the context of React - to pass the ref from a navigator.  The only new file is the first one, I don't think it's a crazy amount of changes.  I also realized you can pass the ref from a regular NavigationContainer and you don't have to create an AppContainer if you are averse to that.  I'll edit to show this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using [a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function useFetchAPI(url, params, headers) {
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState(null);
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(base_url_address + url, { headers: headers })
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log('resp: ', resp);
                if (resp.status == 401) {
                    // this will navigate to your UnAuthorizedLogout page
                    navigation.navigate('UnAuthorizedLogout');
                } else {
                    // otherwise, set the response to result state
                    setResult(resp);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setResult(error.response);
            });
    }, [url])

    return result;
}
```

Comment: can i call this function anywhere in the component, As it contains useeffect so i think it will work on before the return of a component.

Comment: No, cannot. this will be called before return of the component.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your problem. My given solution should be used like this https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/usefetchapi